# React webpack hotload get stuck on index.html after refreshing webpage

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Webpack hotload feature gets stuck on index.html after refreshing web page. It stucks and never goes further than index.html file of the project, which is located under /public/index.html. After it get stucks, I'm able to fix it by editing anything in index.html and refresing webpage, or stop/run project again.

create-react-app's own webpack replaced by our own. This is a must to configure a 3rd party library we use.

I tried like 30+ solutions accross the web, mostly stackoverflow but couldn't managed to solve it.

npm run start script used in **package.json**:

```
 "start": "webpack serve --mode development --progress",
```

Here some code snippets from configurations made to enable hotload and solve this problem:
(since webpack file is too large i only copied the relevant parts. I can copy all if it helps.)

**webpack.config.js**

```
//...
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 3001,
    open: false
},
```

```
plugins: [
    //...
    ...(isProduction ? [] : [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()])
]
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "modules": false
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [

      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      "react-hot-loader/babel",
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
          "loose": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

**index.js**

```
// Internet Explorer 11 requires polyfills and partially supported by this project.
// import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
// import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'typeface-muli';
import './i18n';
import './react-chartjs-2-defaults';
import './styles/index.css';
import App from 'app/App';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

require('react-hot-loader/patch');

const render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <App />
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
};

serviceWorker.unregister();

render();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./app/App', render);
}
```

**App.js**

```
import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';
import FuseAuthorization from '@fuse/core/FuseAuthorization';
import FuseLayout from '@fuse/core/FuseLayout';
import FuseTheme from '@fuse/core/FuseTheme';
import history from '@history';
import { createGenerateClassName, jssPreset, StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import { create } from 'jss';
import jssExtend from 'jss-plugin-extend';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import React from 'react';
import Provider from 'react-redux/es/components/Provider';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
import AppContext from './AppContext';
import { Auth } from './auth';
import routes from './fuse-configs/routesConfig';
import store from './store';

const jss = create({
    ...jssPreset(),
    plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, jssExtend(), rtl()],
    insertionPoint: document.getElementById('jss-insertion-point')
});

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
                routes
            }}
        >
            <StylesProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
                        <Auth>
                            <Router history={history}>
                                <FuseAuthorization>
                                    <FuseTheme>
                                        <FuseLayout />
                                    </FuseTheme>
                                </FuseAuthorization>
                            </Router>
                        </Auth>
                    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                </Provider>
            </StylesProvider>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default hot(App);
```

Any ideas/solutions will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: when you said stuck, did you see it get redirect loop or it just cannot load some resources?

Comment: It just cannot load resources. It just loads index.html and thats all. Its not loading index.js which is root point of project.

Comment: did you check the network tab? did you see any requests stucked at loading?

Comment: There is no requests stucked at loading. Index.html returned with http code 304 (not modified) and also manifest.json returned as response. Thank you.